# PHP - Compare Dates with different format

Tags: php, date

Date Format:

```
 $date1 = '16-MAR-2015';
 $date2 = '04-FEB-15';
```

How can I check if

```
$date1 <= $date2 || $date1 => $date2
```

Do I need to convert date format in

```
 $date1 = '16-3-2015';
 $date2 = '04-2-15';
```

Comment: `$myDateTime = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $dateString);
$newDateString = $myDateTime->format('m/d/Y');` There is a magical function called `strtotime()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this way, it works. [DEMO](http://ideone.com/kal7M9)

```
$date1 = DateTime::createFromFormat('j-M-Y', '16-MAR-2015');
$date2 = DateTime::createFromFormat('j-M-y', '04-FEB-15');
$date1=$date1->format('Y-m-d');
$date2=$date2->format('Y-m-d');
var_dump($date1 <= $date2);
var_dump($date1 >= $date2);
```

Answer (score 5):

Use `strtotime()`:

```
<?php

    $date1 = strtotime("16-MAR-2015");
    $date2 = strtotime("04-FEB-15");

?>
```

and compair

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to convert anything with the given formats, `DateTime` will do what you need.

Just turn them into `DateTime` objects and compare them :

```
$date1 = '16-MAR-2015';
$date2 = '04-FEB-15';

$date1 = date_create($date1);
$date2 = date_create($date2);
// $date1 > $date2 -> true
// $date1 < $date2 -> false
```

Or

```
if (date_create($date1) > date_create($date2)) {
    // Use $date1 unchanged
}
```

Comment: While this is correct be, care with the use of the separators to define MM/DD/YYYY from DD-MM-YYYY in these styled date formats. See http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

Comment: It says `Catchable fatal error: Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string`

Comment: Also if `16-MAR-2015` is comparable to `04-FEB-15` (see year format) using date_create()?

Comment: @Slimshadddyyy You must be trying to use `$date1` somewhere else. Use a temporary variable to do your comparisons such as `$tmpDate1`. Comparisons on DateTime objects is not what throw the fatal error. Not sure I understand what you mean, but yes you could use `if (date_create($date1) > date_create($date2)) {`

Comment: `$date1` is defined once only. Not used anywhere

Answer (score 0):

`$myDateTime = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $dateString); $newDateString = $myDateTime->format('m/d/Y');` There is a magical function called  [strtotime()](http://php.net/strtotime)

If you need to print the value in a readable format you can use the function [DATE](http://php.net/date)

`date("d-m-Y h:i:s",$date1);`

In your  case.
You want to use

> Date.parse()

Comment: soul: How can I use above for `$date1 = '16-MAR-2015' and $date2 = '04-FEB-15';` ?

Comment: convert it `date("d-m-Y h:i:s",$date1);`

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to turn them into a DateTime object.

[DEMO](http://ideone.com/AHEw6f)

```
$date1 = '16-MAR-2015';
$date2 = '04-FEB-15';

$dateComp1 = new DateTime($date1);
$dateComp2 = new DateTime($date2);
```

Then you can compare them, `DateTime` is smart enough to convert the format automatically.

Comment: Expection: `Catchable fatal error: Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string `

Comment: What is your PHP version?

Comment: Be sure you use different variable names than `$date1` and `$date1` for the `DateTime` objects. You won't be able to echo or manipulate them once they are converted.

Comment: they are already different. Why to use `DateTime` and not `strtotime` ? Many roads lead to Rome. And what about `DateTime::createFromFormat('j-M-Y', '16-MAR-2015');` ?

Answer (score -1):

try

```
date1= new DateTime();
date1= new Datetime->format('d-m-Y'); // this will print year 4 digits ie; 2017

date2= new DateTime();
date2= new DateTime->format('d-m-y'); //this will print 2 digit year ie; 17

// to compare

$differance=$date1->diff($date2);

echo $differance->format('d-m-y'); //or change to upper case Y for 4 digit year
```

note... in mysql 5.6 it seems the input format must be `Y` first: if you insert it with `Y`-first format first, it seems to compare correctly no matter what the second format is.